The Hausdorff property and second-countability of projective space.
Def: The $n$-dimensional real projective space, denoted by $\mathbb{RP}^n$ (or sometimes just $\mathbb{P}^n$), is defined as the set of 1-dimensional linear subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$, with the quotient topology determined by the natural map $\pi: \mathbb{R}^{n+1} \setminus \{0\} \to \mathbb{RP}^n$ sending each point $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n+1} \setminus \{0\}$ to the subspace spanned by $x$. For any point $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n+1} \setminus \{0\}$, let $[x] = \pi(x) \in \mathbb{RP}^n$ denote the line spanned by $x$.
Problem :
Prove that the projective space  $\mathbb{RP}^n$ is Hausdorff and second-countable.
My attempt:
For the Hausdorff property, my attempt begins with the plane, i.e., $ \mathbb{RP}^1 $. For two different points $[ \xi ]$ and $[ \eta ]$ in $ \mathbb{RP}^1 $, their representatives in the preimage sets correspond to $\xi$ and $\eta$, respectively. Now, I consider two open conical sets $U$ and $V$, passing through the origin (excluding the origin), which contain $[ \xi ]$ and $[ \eta ]$ respectively, and these regions do not intersect. Consider $P = \pi(U) \subset \mathbb{RP}^1$ and $Q = \pi(V) \subset \mathbb{RP}^1$, which are the sets of lines (i.e., 1-dimensional subspaces) lying within $U$ and $V$, respectively. Clearly, $\pi^{-1}(P) = U$ and $\pi^{-1}(Q) = V$. Since $\pi$ is a quotient map , $U$ and $V$ are open sets in $\mathbb{R}^2$, so $P$ and $Q$ are open sets in $ \mathbb{RP}^1 $ and they do not intersect.
As for the second-countability, I don't have any ideas yet. Is there anyone who can help me?
My confusion:

In my proof of the Hausdorff property, I used geometric intuition. Is there a more analytic proof (or a simpler one)?
Are there any criteria for determining the Hausdorff property of quotient spaces?
I hope someone can give me some hints for the proof of second-countability.


You can prove these two useful results: 1) If $X$ is a compact and Hausdorff topological space, if $\pi:X\to X/\sim$ (the quotient map) is closed,  then the quotient space $X/\sim$ is Hausdorff. 2) If $X$ is a 2-countable topological space and $\pi:X\to X/\sim$ is such that $\pi^{-1}(y)$ is compact for all $y\in X/\sim$, then $X/\sim$ is 2-countable.
